# django update password for User not working

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-authentication

Using django's built in User model I have a basic update password view:

```
class ChangePasswordView(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = ChangePasswordForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_success')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        account = self.request.user.account
        email = account.user.email
        update_password_notification_task.delay(email)
        return redirect(self.success_url)

def password_success(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/password_success.html')
```

its form:

```
class ChangePasswordForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

and its url:

```
path('password/',ChangePasswordView.as_view(template_name='accounts/change_password.html')),
```

And finally, the template:

```
<h1>Change Password...</h1>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button>Change Password</button>
</form>
```

There are no errors, and everything seems to work, but the password is not being updated. I don't know why, I think I did everything, but for some reason after I update the password and get redirected to the `reverse_url` if I try logging out and in, the new password doesn't work.

I don't know what's causing this issue or in what file, so it's hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Where you saves a New Data?

Comment: I thought django handles the saving since I'm using django's PasswordChangeForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly enough all I needed to do add was a `form.save()`:

```
class ChangePasswordView(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = ChangePasswordForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_success')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        account = self.request.user.account
        email = account.user.email
        update_password_notification_task.delay(email)
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```